# sbt 0.13.2-M3 to 0.13.5-RC3 issue

Tags: sbt

I'm having a problem moving from sbt version 0.13.2-M3 to 0.13.5-RC3 where transitive dependencies that 13.2-M3 successfully resolves fail to be resolved by 0.13.5-RC3.

I get unresolved dependency errors where the version is "working@".

It's happening when I have a multi-project build with two sub-projects, one of which depends on the other.  They both have dependencies whose maven poms specify a common parent (though I'm not sure if that's a red herring or not).

It only happens when the dependencies aren't already in the local ivy cache.

A minimal repro Build is:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object BarBuild extends Build {

  val buildSettings = Seq(scalaVersion := "2.10.3")

  lazy val root = Project(
    id = "bar",
    base = file(".")
  ) aggregate(withSolrCore, withSolrClient)

  lazy val withSolrCore = Project(
    id = "withSolrCore",
    base = file("solrCore"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.solr" % "solr-core" % "4.7.1")
    )
  ) dependsOn (withSolrClient)

  lazy val withSolrClient = Project(
    id = "withSolrClient",
    base = file("solrClient"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.solr" % "solr-solrj" % "4.7.1")
    )
  )
}
```

With `build.properties`'s `sbt.version=0.13.5-RC3` I see lots of errors like

```
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.lucene#lucene-analyzers-kuromoji;working@heraclitus.local
```

and

```
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.lucene#lucene-core;working@heraclitus.local: not found
```

but with `sbt.version=0.13.2-M3` everything's peachy.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or something's up with sbt, but at this point I suspect the latter.

Thanks.

Comment: Just saw this report elsewhere. I think this may actually be an issue with Ivy 2.4 and Maven repositories.  You may want to check the Ivy database or check with them on Solr issues.

Comment: As a workaround please use `dependencyOverrides` for the misbehaving module.

Comment: Ok thanks.  13.5 is bumping ivy versions then?

Comment: I'll try dependency overrides though it's a pain since there's ~60 of them.

Comment: :( Yeah.  There's a rule chain you can use to filter programtically, IIRC, but it may not be efficient.

And yes, all of 0.13.1, 0.13.2 and 0.13.5 bumped Ivy revisions to try to pull in fixes.   This looks like an unfortunate consequence.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer and accept. I for one can only partially understand what the solution could be and your answer would get me the better understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a known ivy issue.  The workaround is to override the versions of all the dependencies in the full transitive closure that's breaking with the "real" versions to use.  (I derived the real ones by running update on a stub project with only the problem dependency with an older version of sbt, 0.13.2, which is pre-ivy-bug), like,

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "14.0.1",
  "com.google.protobuf" % "protobuf-java" % "2.5.0",
  "com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap" % "concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru" % "1.2",
  "com.spatial4j" % "spatial4j" % "0.4.1",
  ...
)
```

Comment: Actually, we're going to fix before final.   We just bumped our ivy branch to include the fix: https://github.com/sbt/ivy/pull/8

And I've verified using the example build in this project.